# Python function used 3 times, but only returned once

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm trying to create a function that returns a dictionary and use it 3 times, then join the returned dictionaries into 1. Then assign that dictionary as value to a key in another dictionary. But print(all_dict) only returns 1 dictionary. If I try to print(get_dict(f1)), I get the Traceback below. If instead of calling the same function 3 times, I define each function separately with the same commands in each function, I can get what I want. But I hope to find a more concise way to write code.

You can find HTML of the table here: https://github.com/Tokaalmighty/topmover_table_html/blob/master/html

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "week4_1.py", line 55, in <module>
    print(get_dict(f1))   
  File "week4_1.py", line 23, in get_dict
    bold=topmovers.find_all('b')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Here is the code of my function and how I tried to join 3 dictionaries into 1:

```
def get_dict(f1):

    soup=bs(f1,'html.parser')
    topmovers=soup.find('table'{'class':'topmovers'})
    bold=topmovers.find_all('b')
    …
    …
    return final

all_dict={}
result = {**get_dict(f1), **get_dict(f2), **get_dict(f3)}
all_dict['result']=result
print(all_dict)
print(get_dict(f1))
```

Comment: Your error is a result of `topmovers=soup.find('table',{'class':'topmovers'})` returns a `None`. The problem, so far, is not in your code, but your lack of error-handling. You can't invoke methods against a `None`.

Comment: but it doesn't return a None if I type out the 3 functions entirely..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your original definition of `f1`, `f2` and `f3`, but I suspect it looks something like:

```
f1 = open(...)
```

What's going on, then, is that repeated reads from files start from where the last one left off. If you've read the whole file (like by getting bs to parse it), that will be at the end and subsequent reads come back empty. bs now can't find a table of the appropriate class in the empty file, so it returns `None`.

To fix this, you can reset the files internal pointer back to the start by calling

```
f1.seek(0)
```

Before you use it the second time; or you could avoid duplicating work by capturing the result of the first `get_dict` call in a variable.

Comment: You were right about the definitions for f1, f2 and f3, and assigning returned values to variables indeed made printing each dictionary possible. But it doesn't seem to solve the problem of returning only 1of the 3 dictionaries even after using the unpacking method to join the dictionaries.

Comment: I've figured it out based on the clue you gave! I deleted part of the code because it's related to some online course assignment. The question and answer should still be relevant.

Comment: The problem with joining the dictionaries is, well, joining the dictionaries. Since all of them have the same hardcoded keys, it will pick one value to 'win'. You *could* set it up so each value in the merged dict is a list or set of the values from the component dicts by using a `defaultdict` from collections, and iterate over each key in each dict. But that kind of data structure is very strange, as as your deeply nested single-key dicts. Depending what you want to do, a different data structure probably makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just do this?

f1 is dic 1

f2 is dic 2

f3 is dic 3

It then merges dic f1 and f2 as A1

Then merges A1 and f3 As A1 Again

```
def MergeDic(f1, f2, f3):
    A1 = f1.copy()
    A1.update(f2)
    A1.update(f3)
    return A1
```

Comment: No need for `A2`.. just update A1 again and return it. Or even better, use `collections.ChainMap`.

Comment: Done.. Thanks - Don't know what collections.ChainMap Does so didn't use that

Comment: But that said, OPs way using the ** syntax is perfectly fine and not the source of their problem (which occurs inside `get_dict`).